# lotus notes/ibm notes/domino 9 - how make emails read/unread programmatically in lotus script?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, agent

I have traversed documents in the .nsf database in various ways (as a list of documents in database and/or list of documents in a view) but cannot find where read/unread email mark is stored. Due some large volume message processing I would need to examine each message and determine if read mark is set and according to algorithm mark it as read or not. (read some posts on internet but they apply to v6 - unsure if the same mechanism still applies to v9)

At this stage there is no exact code to show, as I am looking for ideas and suggestions how to do the agent code.

If it cannot be done from Lotus Script (as agent), please advise other better way, as I need to process multiple databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the flag:

flag = notesDocument.GetRead([username] )
Returns true if the current document has been read, otherwise false.
Note  This method is new with Release 8.5.

To update it:

Call notesDocumentCollection.MarkAllUnread( [username] )

Call notesViewEntryCollection.MarkAllRead( [username] )

For more fancy usage it could be with C API (never tested!) have a look at http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/tools/c/5.0.3/api503re.nsf/70cfe734675fd140852561ce00718042/d223db362ddb9e9985256632004f71db?OpenDocument

Comment: First, Thank You for really quick response! 
Method exists (although it is not exposed in lookup in the designer ?!) - and it does work (runtime). I hope it is correct, but to confirm that I would need some time to experiment and double check.
I'd also guess there could be a method: notesDocument.SetRead([username]) or notesDocument.SetUnread([username]) or something simillar.
It would be nice to have a reference for these methods as I need to do couple of more actions for which there is no data in the document  object.

Comment: found! - MarkRead method:  http://notes.helsinki.fi/help/help8_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/5ea0287c7474a81f8525731b004a198d?OpenDocument

there is also MarkUnread

Comment: Yes, doc.Markread(User name) also exists, sorry I didn't mentioned it !
I also have been fooled by my 8.5 help.nsf that don't mention this method! But in the Designer it's usable (even in 8.5)